# Views - List of content that user (ID from URL) voted on

Tags: 7, views, rating

I want to make a list on every profile page of content that the user voted on.

I've yet only managed to show the current logged in user's votes, not the user from the profile page.

In other words, I need to pass the User ID from Contextual filters to the Filter criteria with VotingAPI.

I tried with the filter `Votes: User`, but I wasn't able to set `Is one of: %` as the username, which would've solved my problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Contextual filters by definition should already filter your result set on the field for an entity you choose based on the value of the URL. Did you try setting up the contextual filter to filter on `Votes: User`? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: You're right. I set the filter as `Votes: User` with default value of `User ID from URL` and it worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Actually, it only works if the user in the URL is the logged in user, otherwise it shows no results.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you don't have any other filters to filter by the logged in user. Filters will usually take precedence over contextual filters.

Comment: Fixed it. I think I had a relationship with `Restrict to current user` checked :)

Comment: Glad to see it worked. I added my comment as an answer for future reference :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contextual filters by definition should already filter your result set on the field for an entity you choose based on the value of the URL.

Set up the contextual filter to filter on `Votes: User` and make sure you have no other filters or relationships that restrict your result for the logged in user.